# How can we keep the old ones while the query params add a new query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using `useSearchParams` (`react-router-dom@6`). When I add a new query parameter it deletes the previous ones. How can I prevent this?

When I try this

```javascript
const filterFunc = (valu) => {
  setSearchParams({ star: valu });
}
```

this is happening: `http://localhost:3000/products/search?star=1`

my expectation: `http://localhost:3000/products/search?q=car&star=1`

I adapted this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71974024/20198964) to my own code, but I don't think it's optimal.
code:

```javascript
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
const params = {};

searchParams.forEach((value, key) => {
  params[key] = value;
});
const filterFunc = (star) => {
  params["star"] = star;
  setSearchParams(params);
}
```

Comment: something like `setSearchParams((prev) => ({...prev, { star: value }}));` might do?

Comment: @Nsevens  I tried but it didn't work and the correct spelling is "setSearchParams((prev) => ({ ...prev, star: valu }));" wasn't it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `searchParams` is a [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object. You can call *any* of that object's methods, like [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append) or [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set), to mutate it.

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

...

const filterFunc = (value) => {
  // Add the new query param value to the queryString
  searchParams.set("star", value);

  // Enqueue navigation action that updates the queryString
  setSearchParams(searchParams);
}

...
```

I don't know the exact v6 version it was introduced, but the current version of the `useSearchParams` hook's `setURLSearchParams` updater function can take a callback function that is passed the previous `URLSearchParams` object (*similar to the `React.useState` hook functional state update*).

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

...

const filterFunc = (value) => {
  // Enqueue navigation action that updates the queryString
  setSearchParams(searchParams => {
    // Add the new query param value to the queryString
    searchParams.set("star", value);
    return searchParams;
  });
}

...
```